# Problem with bridge edge loops (total blender n00b)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]

So this happens when I try to bridge the edge loops of these two objects. Can someone explain to me why it happens and how I can make the bridge go "straight"? I have the mirror modifier on. Please explain in a very simple way I am completely new to modeling!

Comment: Firstly apply the mirror modifier. Second go into edit mode, select all faces and press CTRL+N to recalculate the normals. After these steps the bridge edge loops should work just fine.

Comment: can you share your file so that other can see whats the problem is upload your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Every once in while, even with applied scales,  good normals, etc..  bridge edge loops gets confused. In those cases deselect a vert on one loop, and then deselect the corresponding vert on the other and bridge them. Then fill the 2 blank faces manually using f.